# How do i only allow a text box to only have numbers and the following percent symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently building an application and I want a javascript or jquery condition that only allows numbers to be entered into the text box and/or the following percent but i am not sure how to obtain this... I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input) but how do i allow the following percent

Comment: Which of the suggestions in that link do you want to use? For most it is just specifying a regex that covers numbers and I assume the % will always come at the end?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_input").keypress(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace, delete, and percent sign
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37) {
            // let it happen, don't do anything
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ufqse/

Comment: characters can be copy pasted on the text field ,!!  Can you please update the answer...??

Comment: @Aju at that point it would be up to you to decide how to handle that - would you reject the entire pasted content or filter out the invalid characters? I wouldn't say there's a "right" answer for your comment. Definitely multiple approaches that work.

Answer (score 2):

try this one,

```
    $(".common").submit(function(){
    var inputVal = $('#input').val();
    var characterReg = /^[0-9]+%?$/;
    if (!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
        alert('in-correct');
    }
    else
    {
        alert('correct');
    }
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: this will only allow numbers and/or % at the end

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In this you can add what else you want to allow or restrict.

```
$("textboxSelector").keypress(function(e) {
  var key = e.which;
  if ((key < 48 || key > 57) && !(key == 8 || key == 9 || key == 13 || key == 37 || key == 39 || key == 46) ){
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: The character will already be displayed by the time a `keyup` event fires. I think he means to use `keypress`

Comment: @AlienWebguy - Edited my answer, keyup replaced by keydown, it works now. Thanks anways.

Comment: Removed my downvote. I think Matt is right about keypress though. It's relevant with the shift key.

Comment: Yea bro this still doesn't work. I can add `!@#$^&*()` which are not allowed per OP's request.

Comment: @AlienWebguy - It was due to keydown event, changed it to keypress. Now it works fine, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Hehe this is what I came up with

```
    if(!parseInt(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)))
       event.preventDefault();
```

This should be used in the `kepress` jquery event.